# 2 IP Addresses, 1 Host, DNS Records?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, vps

Here's my setup (on a VPS):

- 1 host running Linux (hostname: server1.example.com).
- and 2 ip addresses: 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5 (for that host.)

What I would like to do is to run a web server on the first address and a mail server on the second address having 2 A records in the DNS zones file, something along this lines (pardon my syntax):

```
example.com.       IN     SOA   .........
                                .........

;mail server
mail              IN      A     1.2.3.5
@                 IN      MX    10 mail

;web server
server1           IN      A     1.2.3.4

www               IN      CNAME server1
```

But, if I have understood correctly, this is not possible because the two addresses are actually pointing to the same host (server1). Am I wrong?

The point is, I don't know what to do with the second address, so I thought to run the mail server on it, but then I discovered that it was not possible (or so I have understood)

Is there a solution or I should just forget all about it and keep the spare address for... nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can do it.

1. Test you DNS configuration from external (from a pc out of your network). If you `ping www.example.com` you should receive response from ip 1.2.3.4 and if you `ping mail.example.com` you should receive response from ip 1.2.3.5.
2. Configure web server to listen only on ip 1.2.3.4 and mail server to listen only on ip 1.2.3.5.
3. Verify you services: `telnet www.example.com 80` and `telnet mail.example.com 25`

Comment: Thanks... This destroys what I have understood about DNS configuration but I am glad that my gut feelings where actually correct... I know I should have actually tested the thing, but hey, since I could ask...

Answer (score 0):

Most daemons allow themselves to be configured to bind to specific addresses; investigate their documentation for how.

Comment: I know how to bind the services I run to specific addresses... my problem was with the DNS configuration itself. I never had to do anything like this with DNS up until now and docs on DNS setup are not so clear cut (at least for me, I might be particularly thick)